# Heroku Ruby NoMethodError string.capitalize

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, nomethoderror

I use the following code to group locations depending on the first letter.

mobile_controller:

```
def index
  @locations = Location.all.group_by{|l| l.name[0].capitalize.match(/[A-Z]/) ? l.name[0].capitalize : "#"}
end
```

view:

```
<% @locations.keys.sort.each do |starting_letter| %>
  <%= starting_letter %>
  <% @locations[starting_letter].each do |location| %>
    <%= location.name %>        
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Everything works fine on my local machine, but heroku doesn't like it and keeps showing me this error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `capitalize' for 66:Fixnum):
app/controllers/mobile_controller.rb:13:in `search'
app/controllers/mobile_controller.rb:13:in `search'
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance

**Solution:**
Updated my Heroku Stack to Ruby 1.9.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your local machine is probably on Ruby 1.9, and your Heroku app is running on 1.8.

In Ruby 1.8, calling `String#[]` will give you the character code (a number), whereas Ruby 1.9 will give you a string with the first character.

```
# Ruby 1.8
"test"[0]
# => 116

# Ruby 1.9
"test"[0]
# => "t"
```

You can use `l.name[0..0]` to get around this, or switch to a Ruby 1.9 stack on Heroku.

Comment: Thx! updated my heroku stack to 1.9 and everything works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Under Ruby 1.8, `String#[]` returns the ASCII code of the referenced character rather than the character itself. Try `l.name[0,1].capitalize` in your controller.